# Entity Framework: Tracking changes to FK associations

Tags: entity-framework, poco, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1, code-first

I'm overriding SaveChanges on my DbContext in order to implement an audit log. Working with many-to-many relationships or independent associations is relatively easy as EF creates ObjectStateEntries for any changes to those kinds of relationships.

I am using foreign key associations, and when a relationship between entities changes all you get is an ObjectStateEnty that says for example entity "Title" has "PublisherID" property changed. To a human this is obviously a foreign key in Title entity, but how do I determine this in runtime? Is there a way to translate this change to a "PublisherID" property to let's an EntityKey for the entity that foreign key represents?

I assume I'm dealing with entities that look like this:

```
public sealed class Publisher
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Title> Titles { get; set; }
}

public class Title
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid? PublisherID { get; set; }
    public Publisher Publisher { get; set; }
}
```

There is also EF EntityConfiguration code that defines the relationship and foreign key:

```
public TitleConfiguration()
{
    HasOptional<Publisher>(t => t.Publisher).WithMany(
            p => p.Titles).HasForeignKey(t => t.PublisherID);
}
```

What I'm doing now seems a bit too complicated. I'm hoping there is more elegant way to achieve my goal. For every modified property from ObjectStateEntry I look through all ReferentialConstraints for current entity and see if any of those use it as a foreign key. The code below is called from SaveChanges():

```
private void HandleProperties(ObjectStateEntry entry, 
        ObjectContext ctx)
{
    string[] changedProperties = entry.GetModifiedProperties().ToArray();
    foreach (string propertyName in changedProperties)
    {
        HandleForeignKey(entry, ctx, propertyName);
    }
}

private void HandleForeignKey(ObjectStateEntry entry, 
        ObjectContext ctx, string propertyName)
{
    IEnumerable<IRelatedEnd> relatedEnds = 
            entry.RelationshipManager.GetAllRelatedEnds();

    foreach (IRelatedEnd end in relatedEnds)
    {
        // find foreign key relationships
        AssociationType elementType = end.RelationshipSet.ElementType as 
                AssociationType;
        if (elementType == null || !elementType.IsForeignKey) continue;

        foreach (ReferentialConstraint constraint in 
                elementType.ReferentialConstraints)
        {
            // Multiplicity many means we are looking at a foreign key in a 
            // dependent entity
            // I assume that ToRole will point to a dependent entity, don't 
            // know if it can be FromRole
            Debug.Assert(constraint.ToRole.RelationshipMultiplicity == 
                    RelationshipMultiplicity.Many);
            // If not 1 then it is a composite key I guess. 
            // Becomes a lot more difficult to handle.
            Debug.Assert(constraint.ToProperties.Count == 1);
            EdmProperty prop = constraint.ToProperties[0];

            // entity types of current entity and foreign key entity 
            // must be the same
            if (prop.DeclaringType == entry.EntitySet.ElementType 
                    && propertyName == prop.Name)
            {
                EntityReference principalEntity = end as EntityReference;
                if (principalEntity == null) continue;

                EntityKey newEntity = principalEntity.EntityKey;
                // if there is more than one, the foreign key is composite
                Debug.Assert(newEntity.EntityKeyValues.Length == 1);

                // create an EntityKey for the old foreign key value
                EntityKey oldEntity = null;

                if (entry.OriginalValues[prop.Name] is DBNull)
                {
                    oldEntity = new EntityKey();
                    oldEntity.EntityKeyValues = new[] { 
                        new EntityKeyMember("ID", "NULL") 
                    };
                    oldEntity.EntitySetName = newEntity.EntitySetName;
                }
                else
                {
                    Guid oldGuid = Guid.Parse(
                            entry.OriginalValues[prop.Name].ToString());
                    oldEntity = ctx.CreateEntityKey(newEntity.EntitySetName, 
                            new Publisher()
                            {
                                ID = oldGuid
                            });
                }

                Debug.WriteLine(
                        "Foreign key {0} changed from [{1}: {2}] to [{3}: {4}]", 
                        prop.Name,
                        oldEntity.EntitySetName, oldEntity.EntityKeyValues[0],
                        newEntity.EntitySetName, newEntity.EntityKeyValues[0]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps to illustrate better what I am trying to achieve. Any input is welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: What is wrong with auditing just Id change? If you do audit directly in the database you will also have just changed Id. Btw. if you don't like it why are you using FK associations instead of independent associations?

Comment: I am trying to provide the end user with something more descriptive than PublisherID changed from b087929b-3221-4c43-916b-ad49066969c8 to 6372b8b6-1848-4f7a-ada0-d778a5682d67. Possibly a hyperlink pointing to the entity. So either at point of collecting data for audit log or when displaying the audit log I will need to figure out whether a property is a foreign key and what type of the entity it points to is.

Comment: I read your article about independent associations and was left with a feeling that I might run into some problems later on if I choose to go that route. On top of that if I ever decide to serialize my POCO entities having a proper foreign key value might come in handy. With independent associations I will need to serialize some sort of graph of entities for that data to be useful.

Comment: Yes Guid is not very user friendly but if the main problem is data presentation shouldn't it be solved by some separate query for joining audit with data when creating view? I have to say I did audit in the most of my applications and I never needed this - simply I audited whole row so I knew that it is FK to other table. That's a reason why I wonder why do you need that. Do you audit each changed value as the separate record?

Comment: I was asked to "log the history" not to maintain all previous "versions" of the row exactly. I assume you have a separate audit table for every entity in your database, but I am looking at using one audit table and for all entities and record changes in XML format. I will also store table name and PK of the entity in my audit table.

I'm trying to find a generic solution to tracking changes to relationships that relies on available metadata. As input I get ObjectContext and ObjectStateEntries as output for every changed relationship I want to produce EntityKey for new and old values.

Comment: In such case your current solution looks like way to go.

Comment: Hey look at that the exact same thing I was asked to do and pretty much the exact solution I came up with :-) Well I guess that validates it as the only way to get the job done :-/ Seems like it should be easier to snag this data...

Comment: Call me lazy but I'd just assume Id at the end of the property name meant it was a foreign key or use ForeignKeyAttribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like my code is the right solution to this problem :/

I did end up using independent associations to avoid this problem altogether.