# Linq to Entities Auditing Relationship Updates

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-key-relationship, audit-trail

I am trying to implement generic auditing in my Linq to Entities Object Context.

I have achieved this for the most part with the built in ObjectStateEntry approach, however with this I have identified a flaw and was wondering if there was a way around it.  Take the Example below:

```
tblServer
Server Key    Server Name    ServerTypeKey
1             Server 1       1

tblServerType
ServerTypeKey      Description
1                  Database Server
2                  Web Server
```

Now when using the built in change tracking for tblServer I get the following after changing to ServerTypeKey = 2

Server Key 1 Old Server Type Key [1] New Server Type Key [2].

Is it possible when doing the auditing that the Foregn Key table description can be written out instead of the key value?

Comment: So what do you want instead of the FK value?

Comment: The description from the FK Table 
e.g. Server Key 1 Old Server Type Key [Database Server] New Server Type Key [Web Server].

Comment: Btw. there is parallel question about the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048921/entity-framework-tracking-changes-to-fk-associations