# Track changes to collections using Entity Framework change tracker

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

For auditing/history purposes, I am using the Entity Framework change tracker to determine, before writing changes, what has changed and serialize the changes.  I can get the changed entities by calling `this.ChangeTracker.Entries()` in my `DbContext` derivative and looking at the values for anything marked `EntityState.Added`, `EntityState.Deleted`, or `EntityState.Modified`.  This all works great.

My problem is that this method does not work to track changes to collections of EF objects (for instance, an `ICollection<Person>` property on a `PersonGroup` object).

I'm sure the EF context must track this somehow -- how else would the database update work, after all?  But is it available to me?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6048921/861716) and maybe change your mind.

Comment: @GertArnold I'm guessing there are some changes between EF4 and EF6 because I cannot find this `RelationshipManager` referenced in that code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is relationship change tracking. You can find it in `ObjectStateManager` of the underlying `ObjectContext`, here is how you get all added relationships:

```
//you need to call DetectChanges
((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.DetectChanges();

var addedRelations = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext
                              .ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added)
                                                 .Where(e=>e.IsRelationship).ToList();
```

Comment: I tried this code and the list seems to be empty regardless of the fact that I have added a relationship.

Comment: @Casey see my edit, you need to use `DetectChanges` before checking.

Comment: Have you tried running this?  I still can't seem to get anything after calling `DetectChanges`.

Comment: @Casey in fact that's my experience. BTW is the collection actually a navigation property (which represents relationship)? Also have you tried other states (in my code I use just `Added`).

Comment: Right, that's the type of property I'm interested in.  For a simplified example, imagine a `Supervisor` class with a property of type `ICollection<Employee>` called `DirectReports` or something like that.

Comment: could you post a simple code you tested in your question? I've experienced this and it worked that way.

Comment: @Casey So how is your collection changed? Be sure there is not any SaveChanges() called before.

Comment: The normal way.  obj.Collection.Add.  This code is called before SaveChanges.

Comment: One last, late comment on this:  the call to DetectChanges is not necessary, unless you're not using change-tracking proxies (but if you weren't and you didn't call DetectChanges anywhere your save wouldn't work either).

Comment: @Casey not sure how you experienced that, of course if using `SaveChanges` it will detect changes internally but if you want it to calculate for the modified entities without doing anything special like in this list [Auto detect changes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556205), you then need to call `DetectChanges` manually. I've experienced this and without doing so, the modified entity set is simply empty.

Comment: If you use change tracking proxies SaveChanges is called internally constantly (every time you change something) so you don't need to do it again.

Comment: @Casey where did you read that? `SaveChanges` should be called explicitly to actually run the UPDATE, DELETE or INSERT query. Not sure why you think SaveChanges is redundant when using tracking proxies.

Comment: Sorry; I meant DetectChanges, not SaveChanges.  SaveChanges is not called automatically, but DetectChanges is, every time you update your objects when they are change-tracking proxies.

Answer (score 3):

It turns out you can get at the relationships with this code (assuming it's running inside your `DbContext` derivative):

```
((IObjectContextAdapter) this).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager
     .GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added)
     .Where(e => e.IsRelationship)
     .Select(r => new {EntityKeyInfo = r.CurrentValues[0], 
                       CollectionMemberKeyInfo = r.CurrentValues[1], r.State});
```

Obviously you can tweak this based on what you need and it's up to do you something useful with it.  The first two `CurrentValues` entries represent EntityKey objects which will allow you to get the IDs of the entities in question.

If you want to deal with deleted entities this won't work and you need to use reflection.  Instead of `CurrentValues[0]` and `CurrentValues[1]` you can look at the internal properties `Key0` and `Key1`, which are defined in an internal class you can't access at compile time.  This will work: `r.GetType().GetProperty("Key0", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(r, new object[0])`.  Note that this is probably not an intended use and could blow up whenever.

Comment: you obviously said it's empty right after `.Where(...)`, so how could `Select` project anything?

Comment: @KingKing Well, that's a really good question and I'll have to look at this tomorrow.

Comment: @KingKing Here's your answer -- if you overwrite the list no relations are recorded.  :\ I didn't notice this because I didn't use the same code to test both times.

Comment: what do you mean by ***overwrite the list***?

Comment: @KingKing `obj.collection = context.Objects.Where(e => viewmodel.ListOfIds.Contains(e.Id).ToList()`

Comment: well I'm not sure but as I remember even in that case the relationship change should be recorded (meaning when `SaveChanges` is called, it will be updated correctly, otherwise how could it save the changes?). Of course that's what I experienced so not sure about your specific case.

Comment: @KingKing I can't seem to even reproduce it now so I'm even more confused.  Oh well.  Now it works.

Comment: @Casey, I've just implemented something like this and you don't need to use reflection.  With `.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Deleted).Where(e=>e.IsRelationship..` r.OriginalValues is available in the same format and the opposite happens, r.CurrentValues throws an error